# iOS (Swift): Adding and Removing ImageViews not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, imageview, viewdidload

I have a View Controller that needs to be updated after the method `resetScene()` but for some reason, no ImageViews can be removed or added.

Here is my method for where I am creating the imageViews:

```
let imageName = "checkmark.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 40, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 6.5, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Here is my method for where I am removing the imageViews:

```
func resetScene(){
        print("scene being reset")
        tiles.removeAll()
        targets.removeAll()
        targetCenters.removeAll()
        targetX.removeAll()
        tileX.removeAll()
        tileY = 0
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if view != bannerView {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                print("DONE REMOVING")
            }
        }
        
        indexSelected += 1
        if (userLevel < indexSelected + 1){
            userLevel = indexSelected + 1
        }
        initializeViewDidLoad()
        loadTiles()

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to print `self.view.subviews` after adding `UIImageView`

Comment: Are you sure the `view` object is the same in both those sets of code?  Are you sure you're not re-adding the UIImageViews in `initializeViewDidLoad()` or `loadTiles()`?

Comment: @triple.s after removing the image views I printed self.view.subviews and all it showed was my ad that was running (which is fine). However, the views that I wanted to remove were still shown on the simulator screen, whereas in the logs I supposedly had no image views. Thanks.

Comment: @Putz1103 I am adding different objects in loadTiles() ...I checked to make sure that the objects being added are different - they are, and the positioning of those objects is also different. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this reset on the main thread?  Background thread updating UI is a very bad idea (bad things happen).  And, again, are you sure that the `view` object is the same in both those code snippets?

Comment: It would be nicer to keep track of the views to be removed in an array and then iterate that array when you need to remove them rather than walking the view hierarchy. Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through to make sure your code is doing what you think it is?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, we did set breakpoints. The issue is that the ImageViews aren't being removed or added

Comment: So the code isn't executing (removeFromSuperview) or the views are still there after your call removeFromSuperview? You need to show more code. How do you call,the first code block? How do you call resetScene?

Comment: @Paulw11 according to the logs, the views are not there, but on the simulator the views are still visible